# Существует ли cлово «голашиться»?

Tags: значение-слов, диалекты

Существует ли слово «голашиться»? И если да, то что оно значит?

Answer (score 3):

Ну, если его используют, значит, существует. Это северный диалект. В Костроме так говорят, только вот некий  костромич пишет через А - галашить:

https://www.proza.ru/2017/02/11/1754

Галашить - Шуметь, кричать, суетиться.

Голомя галашиться, галаниться, галанить -  "**голосить, горланить".**

Answer (score 3):

В словарях имеется ***галашиться.***

См. [**СЛОВАРЬ НАРОДНЫХ ГОВОРОВ.  ВЫПУСК ШЕСТОЙ. ИЗДАТЕЛЬСТВО "Н А У К А"**](https://zapdoc.site/a-k-a-d-e-m-i-ya-n-a-u-k-s-s-s-r-institut-russkogo-yazyka-sl8f4bb6b6f5b8680d6e6ef5d8a157530d20374.html):

> **Галашить**, ш у, т и ш ь , *несов., перех. и пеперех.*
>
> 1. *Неперех.* Громко говорить, кричать...
> 2. *Перех.* Будить кого-либо криком...
> 3. *Неперех.* Громко смеяться; зубоскалить.
> 4. *Неперех.* Жить разгульно, кутить...
>
> **Галашиться**, шусь, шиться, *несов.*
>
> 1. Не спать, бодрствовать. Сузд. Влад., 1910.
> 2. Тревожиться, волноваться. Шуйск. Влад., 1912.

Answer (score 1):

В словаре [Даля](http://v-dal.ru/word_s-16521.html):
**галанить** – сев. галачить, **галашить** зап. (от галас южн. зап. голос, шум, крик), горланить, кричать, шуметь; спорить, шумно пустословить, вздорить. | Вят. зубоскалить, гаганить, гагарить. | Кур. кутить, гулять, жить разгульно (голь, голячить? см. также галить и галдить). Галачить кстр-нрх. браниться с криком; **Галашить** костр. то же | сар. будить кого криком, булгачить.

[А. С. Файнбарк](https://books.google.ee/books?id=5y17DQAAQBAJ&pg=PA87&lpg=PA87&dq=%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C&source=bl&ots=_XdWvScbtu&sig=ACfU3U1KhOGAgyBAP5VEX7_1YvMtbk3EJg&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjA6-bglPjfAhUhtosKHc7MDRQQ6AEwCHoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C&f=false) ("Происхождение названий рек и озер бассейнов Верхневолжья и Верхней Мсты"):
р. Галашинский
Вероятно, от рус. (зап.) ***галашить, галачить***, рус. (сев.) ***галанить*** – кричать, шуметь, спорить, пустословить, вздорить; рус. (кстр.) ***галашить*** – браниться с криком...

*Две ночи из пяти обязательно кто-то **галашился**, то какие-то велосипедисты, то какие-то пьяные поляки* (отзыв об отеле).

*Встречал на парадах и Хрущёва с Фурцевой. **Галашились** потом долго мы после этого, один малало был среди нас самое настоящее.* [Считаем, что здесь диалектные слова «галашились», т.е. бурно обсуждали что-то, волновались, и «малало», т.е. очень болтливый человек, говорящий глупости.]
[А. М. Афанасьева. Употребление диалектных слов жителями поселка Савино](https://school-science.ru/4/18/1361)

***Исступленно галашились***, в припадке страсти, утки на болотах.
[Н. П. Смирнов. Лебединый зов](http://sspu.ru/pages/subfaculties/rya/projekts/Batureva.L.P._Mesn_kolorit_Smirnov.pdf)